# pip: dependency links via command line

Tags: python, git, ssh, pip

I want to run a `setup.py` that has several dependency links defined, i.e.:

```
dependency_links=[
    "git+ssh://git@my.gitlab/myproject1.git@v1.4.0#egg=myproject1-1.4.0",
    "git+ssh://git@my.gitlab/myproject2.git@v0.2.0#egg=myproject2-0.2.0",
]
```

My question is whether there is a way to pass this array via command line when running the `pip install` command as follows (e.g.):

```
RUN pip install numpy==1.10.1 \
&& pip wheel --find-links="wheelhouse/" --wheel-dir="wheelhouse/" uwsgi \
&& pip wheel --find-links="wheelhouse/" --wheel-dir="wheelhouse/" --process-dependency-links gitlablink1, gitlablink2 .
```

Comment: Why can't you put it in a `requirements.txt` file and call it with `pip install -r requirements.txt`?

Comment: Ι want to find a relatively secure way of passing command line the `gitlab` token, so I didn't want that to reside within a file. The process will take place within an ephemeral container and I wanted to find an alternative than copying my `~/.ssh` folder